# Data isn't rendering in angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I try to access test json data, it retrieves the data. however it won't display within my template

app.js:

```
var listController = angular.module('ngAppListDemo', []); 

listController.controller('listControl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
   $scope.list = [];
    var urlTest = 'https://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json'; // url 
    //var testData = 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/zemirco/sf-city-lots-json/master/citylots.json'; // .json format
    $http({method: 'GET', url: urlTest}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.list = data;
        console.log(data);         
    });
}]);
```

index.html

```
 <div ng-app="ngAppListDemo">
    <div ng-controller="listControl">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in list">
          <p>{{item.nm}}</p>
        </div><!-- end list item -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

data looks like this within url:

```
[
  {
    "nm": "Edmund lronside",
    "cty": "United Kingdom",
    "hse": "House of Wessex",
    "yrs": "1016"
  },
  {
    "nm": "Cnut",
    "cty": "United Kingdom",
    "hse": "House of Denmark",
    "yrs": "1016-1035"
  },
  {
    "nm": "Harold I Harefoot",
    "cty": "United Kingdom",
    "hse": "House of Denmark",
    "yrs": "1035-1040"
  }
]
```

It's repeating within the template fine. but the data inbetween the `<p>` tags {{ item.nm }} doesn't show. What am I missing?

Edit: It appears that ng-binding is missing once rendering.

Comment: Can you post what the data looks like?

Comment: You really shouldn't use `success` anymore. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: have you tried putting the curlys in quotes?  so "{{item.nm}}".

Comment: "{{item.nm}}" ? @ruby_newbie. noooo why to do this ?

Comment: @MatthewGreen good call. how would you suggest using it? i replaced with `.then(function successCallback(response) { ... ` however, its still not replacing correctly.

Comment: @Modelesq that depends if you updated the assignment like @Alainlb shows in his answer. When using `success` it needs to be `response.data` .

Comment: Your code works for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working example : http://plnkr.co/edit/DeO5fmub16hXutOmylBu?p=preview

try this

```
var listController = angular.module('ngAppListDemo', []); 

listController.controller('listControl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
   $scope.list = [];
    var urlTest = 'https://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json'; // url 
    //var testData = 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/zemirco/sf-city-lots-json/master/citylots.json'; // .json format


    $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: urlTest
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          // the data is in response.data (or data.data using your old paramater name)  not data directly   
          $scope.list = response.data;
           console.log(response.data); 
           // update 1
           $scope.$apply();
      }, function errorCallback(response) {

      });
}]);
```

// update 1:  try a $scope.$apply() to force the view to update

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this. It obviously works. It must be something on my end thats preventing me from displaying it.

Comment: ng-binding is missing from template render

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working without it. But that's the only work around thats worked for me. :\

Comment: try a                $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be working fine.  Created a [demo](http://codepen.io/abhishekjhaji/pen/dGdOzW)
using same html

```
<div ng-app="ngAppListDemo">
<div ng-controller="listControl">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in list">
      <p>{{item.nm}}</p>
    </div><!-- end list item -->
  </div>
</div>
```

May be your css would be having the font and back ground colour same

Comment: I thought so to. Or maybe conflicting js. But theres literally nothing inside the <p></p>. :\

Comment: try {{list}} or {{item}} does it print anything?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't print either option.

Comment: ng-binding isn't there also.

Comment: that means it is not rendering the curly braces {{}} itself. Then this could be issue of character encoding or try copying those braces from somewhere where code is working. Other than that I cant think, why it wouldnt work

Answer (score 0):

After comparing dev inspection from answers with demos. I noticed that I was missing class="ng-binding".

I added :

```
 <span ng-bind="item.nm"></span>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Comment: ng-bind is for replacing the content of a html element. the data her are just string so no need to this directive